# How to re-create Shell Flyout item (set position for the hamburger icon) in .Net Maui?

Tags: maui

While creating Shell flyout item, Hamburger icon is automatically created.

In my application , we need to remove the below mentioned items. [image]

I am unable to re-create the Hamburger icon below.

Target platform - Windows

Unable to create new positon for the auto generated hamburger icon

Comment: I am very interested to see, how you did "remove the below mentioned items". This portion of code will be good place to start. I would place my bet on butchering the whole interface there, not just those items.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code to remove the buttons. Please put the code in the MauiProgram.cs. But if you disable the button you can not use the Flyout.

```
#if WINDOWS
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
            // Make sure to add "using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;" in the top of the file
            events.AddWindows(windowsLifecycleBuilder =>
            {
                windowsLifecycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false;
                    var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                    var id = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
                    var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);
                    switch (appWindow.Presenter)
                    {
                        case Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter overlappedPresenter:
             
                            overlappedPresenter.SetBorderAndTitleBar(false, false);
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
#endif
```